# google search results are https:( how to redirect to http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I having a problem with the way my website pages are being indexed in  google search results.
They are all https instead of http, there are no https urls in my website and iv indexed it as just www.emaxlple.com. My site map also shows all the urls as http://...

here is the .htaccess file im using...

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.webheadz.ie/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Yes, i never tried a 301 redirect before so im not sure if im even close to what im tring to atchive!

any help would be great....im tring to make my websites search results user freindly the last week but im starting to give-up...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will achieve what you are intending:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: I have done an edit on my .htaccess file (the only code my .htaccess file has is the code you givin me)and uploaded it to my root directory...but still no joy:(....if i search google for webheadz there is no problem but when i search for 'web design sligo' my results are usually on the 9th page but are in https...its really cracking me up

Comment: This is working for me in my testing under Apache Server 2.2.  Are you otherwise able to use rewrites?  It's possible your server is configured to prevent execution of rewrites in .htaccess files.

Comment: Hi...im after getting a reply from my hosting and the said i have to use a zeus rewrite....any idea's how to????

Comment: Sorry this is outside of my area of expertise.  Since this question is already marked as answered (thank you!), I think you would get the best result from stack overflow if you asked a new question and included the tag 'zeus'.